# C# Linq Intersect Hashset<T> in memory with IEnumerable<T> from filestream

Tags: c#, linq, memory, file-io

I have this class that exposes an `IEnumerable<Record>` as follows (implementation details left out):

```
public class SomeFileReader() {
    public IEnumerable<Record> Records()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(this.Path, this.Encoding, true))
        {
            var hdr = this.HeaderParser.Parse(sr.ReadLine());  //Parse, but further ignore header (the HeaderParser might throw though)
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                yield return this.RecordParser.Parse(sr.ReadLine()) as Record;
        }
    }
```

A `Record` has, amongst many other properties (and thus being quite large 'memory/storage wise'), an `Id` property (which is a `Key` object that consists of 2 "parts"). For completeness this looks something like:

```
public class Key : IEquatable<Key>
{
    public string OperatorCode { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Key other)
    {
        return (this.OperatorCode.Equals(other.OperatorCode, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            && (this.Key.Equals(other.Key, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }
}
```

The file contains the records in "key order", so it is (guaranteed to be) sorted by the Record's `ID` on-disk.

I also have, in memory, a `HashSet<Key>` of records that I want to process from the `SomeFileReader`. Currently my testfile is only a few megabytes large but I am forseeing this to grow very large in the near future. At this moment I just read the entire file into memory using a `Dictionary<Key, Record>` for easy/fast retrieval of specific records I want to process from my "list" of "to be processed" records. This would be similar to:

```
var recordsfromfile = MyFileImporter.Records().ToDictionary(k => k.Key.Key);
```

This will be problematic once the file grows (too) large ofcourse.

But since I am exposing an `IEnumerable<Record>` I was thinking... I shouldn't have to read the file into memory *completely* since the records are in key order. A simple [Intersect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.intersect.aspx) with my "list" of to-be-processed Keys should suffice. The `Key` already implements `IEquatable` and *should* I need an `IEQualityComparer<Key>` that wouldn't be hard to implement at all. But I (think I) digress..

The `Intersect()` documentation tells me:

> When the object returned by this method is enumerated, Intersect
>   enumerates *`first`*, collecting all distinct elements of that sequence.
>   It then enumerates *`second`*, marking those elements that occur in both
>   sequences. **Finally**, the marked elements are yielded in the order in
>   which they were collected.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

So, if I understand correcly, if *`first`* would be my `IEnumerable<Record>` the file will still be read into memory completely. And even if it would be *`second`* all matches with my 'to-be-processed' "list" would still be read into memory which could still be a very large amount of data. Or am I misreading the documentation and is this "Finally" tripping me up and/or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

What I want to prevent, obviously, is

- a) not reading a large wad of data into memory for the sole purpose of processing some of the records in them one-by-one after which I don't care about those records (the processing will write the result out somewhere else for example)
- b) not (re)opening the same file again and again for each record on my 'to-be-processed' "list" (so I want to be careful not to reset my iterator)

Long story short; will the `Intersect()` do what I want it to do? Should I use another method? Nested for-loop? Any other ideas on how to handle this efficiently?

**EDIT:** Updated to make clear that the "list of to be processed keys" is actually a `HashSet<Key>`.

---

P.s. I was just hit by a brainwave about using Linq for this purpose in bed and can't get to sleep before I figure this out. Unfortunately, I am on vacation and miles away from a decent Visual Studio instance to just simply test this out. That will have to wait until after my vaction (so the misses says... we'll see about that...) [image: smiley]

Comment: As an aside, the body of the `Records` method could be reduced to simply `return File.ReadLines(this.Path, this.Encoding).Select(line => this.RecordParser.Parse(line) as Record)` whilst still maintaining the lazy enumeration behaviour.

Comment: @spender Hmm... d'uh! Why didn't I think of that!?!?

Comment: @spender Crap; I now remember why I did it this way. The file contains one "header" record which has a different layout than the rest of the file so I issue a single readline after opening the streamreader for reading that header and then start reading the file. Added the line in my question.

Comment: @RobIII: It's been a while, but you could have skipped the first line... File.ReadLines(/*...*/).Skip(1).Select(/*...*/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I suspect you actually want:

```
var records = new SomeFileReader().Records()
                                  .Where(record => keys.Contains(record.Key));

foreach (var record in records)
{
    Process(record);
}
```

---

The `Intersect` documentation is wrong, I'm afraid. It actually enumerates `second` first, collecting everything in that... and then streams `first`, yielding any intersecting values.

It also *doesn't* wait until it's seen all the elements before it yields them. See my [Edulinq blog post on `Intersect`](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling/) for more details of what it actually does.

In a TL;DR sense, it's:

- Create a `HashSet<T>` from `second`
- Iterate over `first`

  - For each item, try to remove it from the set
  - If it *was* in the set, yield it; otherwise, don't

The fact that items are removed from the set as we go stops the same element from being yielded twice (even if it occurred more than once in both `first` and `second`, due to it being a set).

Basically, I think you'll be okay so long as you reverse the order of the operands, so you do:

```
var result = streamingRecordsFromFile.Intersect(smallCollectionInMemory);
```

Comment: I am very sorry to have to ask *the* Jon Skeet for a clarification and I'm afraid my drowsiness is to blame, but could you clarify a bit more? **EDIT**: Ah, you posted a link to a blogpost. I'll go read that first. Thanks! **EDIT2**: Thanks for your verification (or your educated guess judging from the "I think..." part). I'm afraid there's only one way to be sure: wait until I get my hands on a Visual Studio running PC/Laptop and simply try/test it. **EDIT3**: On the Hashset: that is what my actual "to be processed" `List<Key>` is; I complicated it a bit too much maybe.

Comment: @RobIII: Yes, you've got a `List<Key>` at the moment, but `Intersect` will create a *new* `HashSet<Key>` to keep track of which keys can still be returned.

Comment: No, to clarify: in my question I said I had a `List<Key>` but (not remembering the details correctly and I don't have the actual code with me) the actual "to be processed list" already **is** a `Hashset<Key>`. And now I have a problem I guess. Ofcourse I need the *actual records* to be returned from `Intersect` (which, clearly, d'oh, it doesn't) to be processed. So I may need to rethink my initial brainwave... The list of "which records need to be processed" is determined by another `Intersect()` which gave me the HashSet<Key> as a result obviously. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @RobIII: Do you just need `streamOfRecords.Where(record => keys.Contains(record.Key))`?

Comment: May well be. As long as it doesn't read the entire file into memory and doesn't re-open or "re-seek" the file for each to-be-processed record (which, I guess, now thinking about it, it won't...) then I do. Maybe I'm overthinking this and maybe I should just go get my well deserved sleep... It may well be just that simple indeed... In any case; I do thank you very, very much for thinking along with me and helping me see the obvious. Now I'll go sit in a quiet corner and be ashamed for a while if you don't mind...